# Get current cursor position from TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, next.js, tinymce

I have tried to get the current cursor position inside TinyMCE, but to no avail.

What I want is to create a change control, obtaining at what point the entire "textarea" begins to be written within TinyMCE to later save the text I entered to a database so that another person can review the text change and accept it. Or not.

I already tried with `selectionStart`, but it doesn't return anything, also with `bookmark` but it's only temporary and with `selection.getSelect()` it only gives me the position of the line I click, let's say I have 3 jumps of line all with 10 characters but if I click in the middle of line 2 instead of giving me the number 15 it returns me the 5 and also in line 1 and 3.

Is there a way to get the position of the pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this example of setting and getting the cursor position using TinyMCE's Bookmark Manager API:

http://fiddle.tiny.cloud/yoiaab/1

```
let tinyBookmark;
function setCursor() {
    tinyBookmark = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getBookmark(2);
}

function getCursor() {
    console.log(tinyBookmark);
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus()
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.moveToBookmark(tinyBookmark); 
}
```

The tinyBookmark object can be stored in your db (console logged in the getCursor function).

Docs:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.dom.bookmarkmanager/#BookmarkManager